# how to retrieve data from two input fields simultaniously after submission with one submission?

Tags: php, html

I have an input textarea, a submit button, and an Output textarea.

Essentially, when text has been inputted into the inputTextarea then after submission it sends itself to the OutputTextarea.

I want to read the string lengths of both textareas.

Why, I could just read the first since its the same data?

Here's the catch, I input text into the first field and i have some logic which takes said data and converts it into something else, therefore I need a little statistic for comparison.

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
   <head>

    <title>Compression</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css"></style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CompressionStyle.css">


    <!-- VALUE DECLARATION -->
    <?php

        $BinaryCodeInput = $_GET['InputBinaryCode'];
        $CompressedCodeOutput = $_GET['OutputCompressedCode'];

         $digits = str_split($BinaryCodeInput, 4);

             $replace = array(

                     "" => "",
                     " " => "",
                     "1" => "x",
                     "0" => "y",    
                     "00" => "Q",
                     "11" => "R",
                     "01" => "S",
                     "10" => "T",
                     "000" => "U",
                     "001" => "V",
                     "010" => "W",
                     "100" => "X",
                     "111" => "Y",
                     "110" => "Z",
                     "101" => "s",
                     "011" => "z",
                     "1111" => "A",
                     "1110" => "B",
                     "1101" => "C",
                     "1011" => "D",
                     "0111" => "E",                                  
                     "0110" => "F",
                     "1001" => "G",
                     "0101" => "H",
                     "1010" => "I",
                     "0011" => "J",
                     "1100" => "K",
                     "1000" => "L",
                     "0100" => "M",
                     "0010" => "N",
                     "0001" => "O",
                     "0000" => "P"

                    );

                    foreach ($digits as $val) {
                        //str_replace(' ', '', $digits);
                        $replace[$val];
                    }   

                 $CompressedOutputLength =  strlen($CompressedCodeOutput);  

      ?>

</head>
    <body>

        <div class="formOne"> 
            <!-- //INPUT GOES HERE -->
            <form action="#" method="GET">

                <!-- LABEL FOR BINARY CODE INPUT -->
                <label id="Lenter">Enter Binary Code</label>

                <!-- INPUT AREA -->
                <textarea cols="54" rows="5" name="InputBinaryCode" style="border:dotted 4px black"></textarea>

                <!-- SUBMIT BUTTON -->
                <input type="submit" value="Compress">

                <br>
                <br>

                <!-- LABEL FOR COMPRESSION OUTPU -->
                <label id="Loutput">Compressed Code</label>

                <!-- COMPRESSED TEXT AREA -->
                <textarea disabled="yes" cols="54" rows="5" name="OutputCompressedCode" style="border: dotted 4px black"><?php

                         foreach ($digits as $val) {
                        //str_replace(' ', '', $digits);
                        echo $replace[$val];



                     }

                         //$CompressedOutputLength = strlen($val);
                        ?></textarea>

                <!-- SPACERLINE -->
                <hr/>

                <!-- STATISTICS SECTION -->
                <p>Original Code Length: <?php echo strlen($BinaryCodeInput);  ?></p>
                <p>Compressed Output Code Length: <?php  echo $CompressedOutputLength;  ?></p>


            </form>
        </div>
</body>
```

As you can see this works, but the problem is, that to get data from the Output source I'll have to press the submit button twice, therefore losing the current output in the output field.

Comment: _"I have some logic which takes said data and converts it into something else"_... when/where is this done? Is this shown in your question?

Comment: @Don'tPanic No it isn't nor is it needed in this context

Comment: I can't see a problem with this code. the problem exist at the client where you fill your second textarea . However, since you didn't show how you did, no one knows

Comment: @Accountantم I was missing an attribute, You cant edit the second textarea, text goes into the first field, goes through some logic (not added in post), then sends it  to the last field. What i want is that when the submit button is pressed, the statistics field, where it shows stringlengths, both the first Input string length and output string length will be output simultaneously, right now when i press the submit button i only get the InputText string length and then if i press it again i get the output, which i do not want, i want both of them at the same time

Comment: Have you tried this with AJAX?

Comment: @MohammedAkhtarZuberi sso with java script? i did find this :     `<script>
                $(window).load(function(){
                    $("#one, #two").on("change keyup", function(){
                        $("textarea").not($(this)).val($(this).val());
                    });
                });
            </script>`

But this isnt essentially a solution, its syncing the two areas yea, i guess i can use this but this means i am not submitting to get an output rather just the statistics..Another problem with that is that i'll lose the text in output after submission

Comment: Since your "Logic" is not clear, therefore I have created my own logic and modified the code. Check the answer shortly.

Comment: @MohammedAkhtarZuberi i re did the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the below steps in your entire process

1. Input Text
2. Submit Form
3. Process the Input Text based on your logic
4. Output your processed text
5. Print Output Text length

Below is the modified code based on your logic. Please note that I have created a new variable `$output_val` to store the processed value. I calculated the length and stored in `$len_output` of this variable and printed.

```
   <head>

<title>Compression</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css"></style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CompressionStyle.css">


<!-- VALUE DECLARATION -->
<?php

    $BinaryCodeInput = $_GET['InputBinaryCode'];
    $CompressedCodeOutput = $_GET['OutputCompressedCode'];

     $digits = str_split($BinaryCodeInput, 4);

         $replace = array(

                 "" => "",
                 " " => "",
                 "1" => "x",
                 "0" => "y",    
                 "00" => "Q",
                 "11" => "R",
                 "01" => "S",
                 "10" => "T",
                 "000" => "U",
                 "001" => "V",
                 "010" => "W",
                 "100" => "X",
                 "111" => "Y",
                 "110" => "Z",
                 "101" => "s",
                 "011" => "z",
                 "1111" => "A",
                 "1110" => "B",
                 "1101" => "C",
                 "1011" => "D",
                 "0111" => "E",                                  
                 "0110" => "F",
                 "1001" => "G",
                 "0101" => "H",
                 "1010" => "I",
                 "0011" => "J",
                 "1100" => "K",
                 "1000" => "L",
                 "0100" => "M",
                 "0010" => "N",
                 "0001" => "O",
                 "0000" => "P"

                );

                $output_val = "";

                foreach ($digits as $val) {
                    //str_replace(' ', '', $digits);
                    $replace[$val];

                    $output_val = $output_val . $replace[$val];
                }   

                $CompressedOutputLength =  strlen($CompressedCodeOutput);

                $len_output = strlen($output_val);

  ?>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="formOne"> 
        <!-- //INPUT GOES HERE -->
        <form action="#" method="GET">

            <!-- LABEL FOR BINARY CODE INPUT -->
            <label id="Lenter">Enter Binary Code</label>

            <!-- INPUT AREA -->
            <textarea cols="54" rows="5" name="InputBinaryCode" style="border:dotted 4px black"></textarea>

            <!-- SUBMIT BUTTON -->
            <input type="submit" value="Compress">

            <br>
            <br>

            <!-- LABEL FOR COMPRESSION OUTPU -->
            <label id="Loutput">Compressed Code</label>

            <!-- COMPRESSED TEXT AREA -->
            <textarea disabled="yes" cols="54" rows="5" name="OutputCompressedCode" style="border: dotted 4px black"><?php

                     foreach ($digits as $val) {
                        //str_replace(' ', '', $digits);
                        echo $replace[$val];

                     }

                     //$CompressedOutputLength = strlen($val);
                    ?></textarea>

            <!-- SPACERLINE -->
            <hr/>

            <?php echo $output_val; ?>

            <!-- STATISTICS SECTION -->
            <p>Original Code Length: <?php echo strlen($BinaryCodeInput);  ?></p>
            <p>Compressed Output Code Length: <?php  echo $len_output;  ?></p>


        </form>
    </div>
```

In this code, I have added 20 to the Input Text value (for the understanding I entered only numbers) as an alternate to your Logic. After that displayed the `$output_new` and its length.

As a simple rule, it is always a good idea to use values from where they are originated rather than from the output field. In your case, I have stored the output value in a variable and used it wherever required, i.e. to output in Output Textarea and to calculate the length.

Comment: I have modified the answer based on your updated question. This works now as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

strlen() will return NULL on an empty value, so for the last line, change it to this:

```
<p>Output String Length: <?php echo (strlen($OutputText)) ? strlen($OutputText) : '0';  ?> </p>
```

This will give a fallback to zero in the case there isn't a value set already.

Comment: This doesn't seem to change anything.